# ConcurrentQueue<string> with multithreading/tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

How could I add multithreading to a Concurrentqueue, at the moment I'm currently processing a text file using Concurrentqueue on 1 thread, but what if I wanted to run it on multiple threads in order to decrease overall processing time?

Example of current methods -

```
    private static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"));
        Process();

    }

    static void Process()
    {

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            string entry;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out entry))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
                log("out.txt", entry);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void log(string file, string data)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(file))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(data);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Break down of code -

```
queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(System..) // assigns queue to a text file

Process(); // Executes the Process method


static void Process() {

    while ... // runs a loop whilst queue.count is not equal to 0

    if (queueTryDequeue... // takes one line from queue and assigns it to 'string entry'

    Console.. // Writes 'entry' to console

    log.. // adds 'string entry' to a new line inside 'out.txt'
```

input.txt for example contains 1000 entries, and I want to create 10 threads which take a entry from input.txt and process it, whilst avoiding using the same entry/duplicating the same process as another thread.. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Depends a lot on what _and process it_ means here. CPU or I/O bound ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) loop:

**Note**: it will not loop the items in the original order!

```
private static StreamWriter logger;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Store your entries from a file in a queue.
    ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"));

    // Open StreamWriter here.
    logger = File.AppendText("log.txt");

    // Call process method.
    ProcessParallel(queue);

    // Close the StreamWriter after processing is done.
    logger.Close();
}

static void ProcessParallel(ConcurrentQueue<string> collection)
{
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions()
    {
        // A max of 10 threads can access the file at one time.
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
    };

    // Start the loop and store the result, so we can check if all the threads are done.
    // The Parallel.For will do all the mutlithreading for you!
    ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, collection.Count, options, (i) =>
    {
        string entry;
        if (collection.TryDequeue(out entry))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
            log(entry);
        }
    });
    // Parallel.ForEach can also be used.

    // Block the main thread while it is still processing the entries...
    while (!result.IsCompleted) ;

    // Every thread is done
    Console.WriteLine("Multithreaded loop is done!");
}

private static void log(string data)
{
    if (logger.BaseStream == null)
    {
        // Cannot log, because logger.Close(); was called.
        return;
    }

    logger.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, however if I try to use my log method instead of the one you provided, it throws a exception ' the process cannot access this file, because it is being used by another process '.. unless I take your approach and set logger inside main to "log.txt"

Comment: I've marked as correct answer, since this question is regarding threading & your answer is in working order for that.

Comment: @R2-D2 Your approach to logging is not working because the loop is logging on multiple threads at the same time. The log function opens the 'log.txt' file, writes something and closes it. If another thread accesses the log method while another thread is still writing to the log file, you will receive that exception, the 'lock' on the file must be removed first by calling `writer.Close();`.